# permission denied with shell.application

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript code to run notepade.exe:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
  function executeCommands()
   {            
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");     
    var commandtoRun ="C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";
    oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","", "open", "1");               
  }
</SCRIPT>
```

The problem is that, when i run the script then it give error..."Permission denied."

Can anybody help me on this matter?

Answer (score 10):

It's necessary to have two settings turned on.

1. **Enable unsigned ActiveX controls for the current zone**

   Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level... 

   Enable "ActiveX Controls and plug-ins" > "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting"
2. **Allow Active Content to run files**

   Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security
   Enable "Allow Active Content to run in files on My Computer"


   **** Make sure to close all your IE browser windows.**

Comment: is there a chrome equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You may experience a "Permission denied" error, which means that the browser will not let script execute outside the "sandbox".  Try solving the issue by changing a security setting in the browser:

- Internet Options, Advanced, Security:
- "Allow Active Content to run in files on My Computer"

The above is for IE, but most browsers have similar options.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, weirdly, I had this issue when running a .html file I'd created on my desktop into IE... but when I moved the file onto a WAMPServer it worked okay; Not quite sure why that should solve the problem, but maybe that'll help someone!?