# ShellExecute permission denied in windows

Tags: javascript, windows-shell, activexobject

Can someone tell me why permission is denied to run a shell command in windows and how to resolve?

```
function executeCommands(inputparms)
{
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var commandtoRun = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Notepad.exe";
  if (inputparms != "")
  {
    var commandParms = document.Form1.filename.value;
  }
  oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, "", "open", "1");
}
```

Comment: Check at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4496681/1776042

Comment: @lqs,i did changes to the settings but even after the browser and system restart,changes are not saved(showing "*")

Comment: This code will only work with IE. Chrome, Opera, Firefox, ... don't support ActiveXObject.

Answer (score 6):

It's necessary to have two settings turned on.

1. **Enable unsigned ActiveX controls for the current zone**

   Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level... 

   Enable "ActiveX Controls and plug-ins" > "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting"
2. **Allow Active Content to run files**

   Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security
   Enable "Allow Active Content to run in files on My Computer"


   **** Make sure to close all your IE browser windows.**

Note : as displayed at the bottom of the "Internet Options > Advanced > Security" block, the computer must be restarted for this option to be taken into account.