# ShellExecute permission denied SCRIPT70, IE11 windows 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, activex, shellexecute

i'm using activeX shell application to run file in local. IE11 vrsion 11.316.17763.0
windows 10

I run into an error when trying to execute shellexecute part. script70 permission denied.

ive enabled necessary setting to run activeX as well as advanced->security->allow active content to run files on my computer

even so the error still happens.

please help how to clear this error and make shellexecute run successfully.

Comment: anyone? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you had already enable the option **allow active content to run files on my computer**

I suggest you to also try to enable the option **Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting**

**Enable unsigned ActiveX controls for the current zone**

> Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level...  Enable "ActiveX
>   Controls and plug-ins" > "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not
>   marked as safe for scripting"

[image]

Reference:

[permission denied with shell.application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496681/permission-denied-with-shell-application/15619828)

Comment: thanks @Deepak-MSFT , the option on my setting is greyed out. my current zone is Local Intranet. is it normal for windows 10?

Comment: If it is grayed out which means your organization had set group policies for it. https://i.postimg.cc/0NHhtMyw/104.png You can try to contact your administrator to enable this option for you. Ref: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/microsoft_internet_explorer_11/2017-12-12/finding/V-46501 and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fdcc/2011/11/03/enabling-initialize-and-script-activex-controls-not-marked-as-safe-in-any-zone-can-get-you-hurt-bad/

Comment: it would seem that is the case..on same related question, other than using activeX is there any way I can run local file from web? I didn't have much choice but to do it however it take..

Comment: for those wondering about the same thing as me, i've found the solution but I wont reveal it here for legal issue. pls drop in my inbox to know more.